# How do you calculate the fluid flowing through a pipe using a flux integral?

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals, fluid-dynamics

I am beginning to learn vector calculus and over the last few days I have been looking at integrals.

An example the lecturer used was fluid flow. He said that the volume of fluid flowing through a small area $\delta S$ in time $\delta t$ is $(\mathbf{u} \cdot \delta\mathbf{S})\delta t$, where $\mathbf{u}$ is the velocity field of the fluid. He followed it by saying the total amount of fluid flowing through the whole surface $S$ in time $\delta t$ is $$\delta t \int_S \mathbf{u} \cdot d \mathbf{S}.$$

For whatever reason, he wrote the expression in the form above, not as an equation (i.e. something with an equals sign). So is the correct equation $$\delta \Phi = \delta t \int_S \mathbf{u} \cdot d \mathbf{S},$$ or $$\Phi = \delta t \int_S \mathbf{u} \cdot d \mathbf{S}?$$

The use of $\delta t$ rather than $dt$ is confusing me because it is unclear if he means to say $\delta t \to dt$ or something else.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: With fluids, one has to be careful if we're in an Eulerian frame vs a Langrangian frame. The nuance means that a time derivative is actually different between both frames (the buzzword being material derivative). However that nuance is all encapsulated in the "variational" notation with $\delta t$'s and such instead of the $dt$'s which mean something very specific.

Comment: It depends what you mean by $\Phi$

Comment: @Michaël I don't know exactly, because the lecturer never wrote the LHS of the equation himself. The words he used to describe the expression were "the total amount of fluid that passes over $S$ in time $\delta t$" and then proceeded to write the integral.

Comment: @GibbNotGibbs This integral is not part of an equation here but is just a definition of the total volume of fluid that passes through S in a time $\delta t$. You can call this quantity how you want: $\Phi$, $\delta \Phi$, V,.... (You can check in terms of units that this is indeed a volume: the SI unit of $\delta t (\pmb{u} \cdot d\pmb{S})$ is s $\times$ $($m$/$s $\times$ m$^2)$ $=$ m$^3$. The integral then just sums over all the $\delta \pmb{S}$ to find the volume through $S$.) The time $\delta t$ is also just a name and can be large or small (at least if $\pmb{u}$ is time-independent).

Comment: @Michaël I realise that the integral is giving us the total volume, but I'm not sure about the rest. As in, if the lecturer is implicitly saying $\delta t \to dt$, then it would make sense to say $$\frac{d\Phi}{dt}=\int_S \mathbf{u} \cdot d\mathbf{S},$$ whereas if $\delta t$ is not to be treated as an infinitesimal quantity, then we would be saying $$\Phi=\delta t \int_S \mathbf{u} \cdot d\mathbf{S},$$ which are clearly stating different things. Hopefully that makes sense

Comment: It's hard to tell without context. Did the lecturer mention this $\Phi$ or did you just introduce it here? Does he use $\delta t$ next and if so in what context? As the first comment said, one should also mind whether working in an Eulerian or a Lagrangian frame.

Comment: I added $\Phi$ myself: I tried googling to see what standard notation for volume of a fluid was, and what I saw indicated it was $\Phi$.

As to the question of frames, I can't say. The lecturer did not mention this distinction and I was unfamiliar with it until now.

For reference, I will be starting the first year of my maths degree in September — what I am studying now is simply reading ahead because I enjoy it. Consequently, it is entirely possible I am missing some relevant background knowledge.

Comment: I can't think of a physical quantity that would be represented by this $\Phi$ in your equations. My guess is that the expression is given as such to define the total volume of fluid that passes through $S$ in a time $\delta t$ in mathematical terms, in order to use it next in some other calculation. I don't think it is meant as an equation where a certain quantity $\Phi$ or $\frac{d\Phi}{dt}$ has to equal the integral. (Sorry for the late reply, I didn't see you had answered)